# Listview lags even when images are cached using Picasso

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, picasso

I have a list view which contains images and when I scroll after a certain point, the scrolling lags.

I am using `Picasso` and the following code to make sure the images are loaded into memory in a background thread.

```
    picasso
        .load(f)
        .fit()
        .error(R.drawable.broken_image)
        .into(viewHolder.imageView, loadDoneCallback);
```

If all my `ListView` entries are loading the same image, there is no lag, so it seems like the issue is definitely related to loading the image from memory to the `viewHolder.imageView`.

Another data point is that I am seeing the lag on my O+O device running `Android 4.4.4`. However, my Nexus 5, which is running `Android 5.1` doesn't seem to have this issue. Both seem to be using a heap size of around 128MB+. At ~40KB per thumb and 3 thumbs per row, and total of 50 rows (I see the lag when I go past the first 10 rows), my total image size in memory should be ~6MB and all images should fit in cache (even though loading is anyways done in a background thread).

When I recreated the issue multiple times by scrolling up and down, I managed to get the `Skipped x frames` message.

```
06-03 22:24:30.279    2382-2382/xxx I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Again, I am assuming this work that is happening in the main thread is related to the individual images which are loaded by `Picasso` from its cache to the `ImageView`. I am assuming it can't be related to any other layout related calculations etc, since using the same image for all `ListView` entries works perfectly.

Is this expected or am I making some rookie mistake?

UPDATE: This is my `getView` code

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    final String imageId = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.image_row_home, parent, false);
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        viewHolder.imageView.getLayoutParams().height = imageWidth;
        viewHolder.imageView.getLayoutParams().width = imageWidth;
        viewHolder.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        viewHolder.imageId = imageId;
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        viewHolder = ((ViewHolder) view.getTag());
        // If this view is already for the image we want, no need to recreate it.
        if (viewHolder.imageId.equals(imageId)) {
            return view;
        }
        viewHolder.imageId = imageId;
    }

    final File f = getImageFileForPosition(position);
    picasso
        .load(f)
        .fit()
        .error(R.drawable.broken_image)
        .into(viewHolder.imageView);
}
```

Comment: The assumption that the Skipped Frames message happens because of Picasso is not correct, it would be great if you could post some of the code that loads data into the ListView, my hunch is that something else is hogging the main thread

Comment: I believe this is one of the main reasons Google created `RecyclerView`, because `ListView` gets very cumbersome on the system when it gets very large. That and customization opportunity.

Comment: @TommySM: Updated the question with my `getView()` code
@JoeBruzek: I thought `ListView` does recycling as well. Will check `RecycleView`. However, given that I do not see this issue when the same image is loaded in all the `ListView` rows, I was assuming this had something to do with how the data is getting loaded from memory to the `ImageView`

Comment: I don't see any immediate wrongness.. what goes on inside getImageFileForPosition()?

Comment: @TommySM: Is just generates a File object using an id. 
        `File file = new File(
                thumbnailDir + "/" + Constants.THUMBNAIL_FILENAME_PREFIX + imageId + ".jpg");`. Based on some picasso issues [#507](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/507) and [#376](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/376), looks like this can be due to large numbers of images getting loaded.

Comment: well, than I think you should open an issue thread similar to this [1055](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1055) , Jake Wharton is also active here, so rephrasing your question might do the trick.

Comment: @wislo I'm running into something similar. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @dal102 nope, didn't really figure this one out.